# case statement - adding hours starting hour from the certain date

Tags: sql

The third party downloaded work hours incorrectly. They subtracted 6 hours. I was trying to add 6 hours starting from June 25 to punch_start and punch_end. I needed shift time (punch_time_list) to reflect this change.
My view is:

```
ALTER view  [dbo].[vw_view]
as
select distinct org, 
    org_abbr,
    employee,
    punch_system_ID, 
    cast ( punch_start as datetime) as punch_start,
    cast (punch_end as datetime) as punch_end, 
    cast(cast (punch_start as time(0)) as nvarchar) + ' - ' + cast (cast (punch_end as time(0)) as nvarchar) as punch_time_list,
    punch_hours             
from tblTable
group by org_abbr, org, employee, punch_system_ID, punch_start, punch_end, punch_hours
GO
```

I modified my code:

```
ALTER view  [dbo].[vw_view] as
select distinct org, 
        org_abbr,
        employee,
        punch_system_ID,
        dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_start as datetime)) as punch_start, 
        dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_end as datetime)) as punch_end, 
        cast(dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_start as time(0)))  as nvarchar) + ' - ' + cast (dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_end as time(0)))  as nvarchar) as punch_time_list,
        punch_hours,
        cast(date_load as date) as date_load
        from tblTable 
group by org_abbr, org, employee, punch_system_ID, punch_start, punch_end, punch_hours, date_load
```

And I got the needed result with adding 6 hours.

Now I need you help with creating 'case when' statement specifying the starting date these 6 hours should be added.
Should I use something like this:

```
(case when punch_start >= '2022-07-25 00:00:00.000' then  dateadd(hour, 6, cast(punch_start as datetime)) else dateadd(hour, 0, cast(punch_start as datetime)) end) as punch_start
```

I think I found the solution:
(case when punch_start >= '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then  dateadd(hour, 6, cast(punch_end as datetime))
when punch_start < '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then  dateadd(hour, 0, cast(punch_start as datetime)) end) as punch_start,
(case when punch_end >= '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then  dateadd(hour, 6, cast(punch_end as datetime))
when punch_end < '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then  dateadd(hour, 0, cast(punch_end as datetime)) end) as punch_end,
(case when punch_end >= '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then cast(dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_start as time(0)))  as nvarchar) + ' - ' + cast (dateadd(hour, 6, cast (punch_end as time(0)))  as nvarchar)
when punch_end < '2022-06-25 00:00:00.000' then cast(dateadd(hour, 0, cast (punch_start as time(0)))  as nvarchar) + ' - ' + cast (dateadd(hour, 0, cast (punch_end as time(0)))  as nvarchar) end)  as punch_time_list,

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (oracle, sql server, mysql, postrgres, etc)?

Comment: sql serverI think I found the solution: